# Dynamic listing of drop-down list in Smartsheet using python API

Tags: python-3.x, smartsheet-api-2.0

I want to populate the drop-down list in a smartsheet from data in a column of another smartsheet. Is it possible? Do I need cross sheet referencing for it ? How do I access the drop-down list?

Answer (score 0):

First read the source sheet, remove blanks, duplicate, and wrong data. then to edit a drop down list column you'll have to edit the options : https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#update-column

Note : The company I am working for is selling an automation to automaticly perform such requirements : https://smarterbusinessprocesses.com/smartercontrols4smartsheet-dropdown-list-manager-one-to-many/  .